# Ruby, capture ending portion of string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have many strings in the following format. Only the portion after the last "/" is different...

```
"http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/user_name%40gmail.com/public/basic/_8gq3ecpo6gp3ib9n8h0jeb9k8l13ab9o85346b9k8gqk4g9h74s4aea26s"
```

I need to capture only the portion after the last "/".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`str.split('/').last` where `str` is your string

Comment: Ah! And I had been banging my head with regex's for way too long! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use regexes when not necessary

```
s = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/user_name%40gmail.com/public/basic/_8gq3ecpo6gp3ib9n8h0jeb9k8l13ab9o85346b9k8gqk4g9h74s4aea26s"

s.split('/').last # => "_8gq3ecpo6gp3ib9n8h0jeb9k8l13ab9o85346b9k8gqk4g9h74s4aea26s"
```

Answer (score 3):

Splitting the string on `/` is one way, as shown in other answers.

URLs are basically filenames, so you can also use `File.basename`:

```
File.basename('http://example.com/foo')
=> "foo"
```

Or, in your case:

```
File.basename("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/user_name%40gmail.com/public/basic/_8gq3ecpo6gp3ib9n8h0jeb9k8l13ab9o85346b9k8gqk4g9h74s4aea26s")
=> "_8gq3ecpo6gp3ib9n8h0jeb9k8l13ab9o85346b9k8gqk4g9h74s4aea26s"
```

Technically, the correct way to do it is to treat the URL as what it is, and break it apart using tools designed to do that:

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI.parse("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/user_name%40gmail.com/public/basic/_8gq3ecpo6gp3ib9n8h0jeb9k8l13ab9o85346b9k8gqk4g9h74s4aea26s")
File.basename(uri.path)
=> "_8gq3ecpo6gp3ib9n8h0jeb9k8l13ab9o85346b9k8gqk4g9h74s4aea26s"
```

But, it's pretty trivial to do it the other way, and is usually safe.